# Unable to modify externalTrafficPolicy

Tags: azure-aks, azure-load-balancer, x-forwarded-for

I need to preserve source IPs until they reach my destination containers (X-Forwarded-For headers); on web, the solutions/suggestions are leading me to that it's to change externalTrafficPolicy to 'Local' on LB service definition; yet, using kubectl edit or patch didn't work (Azure platform keeps reverting the changes i've just made to their defaults). I use AKS managed Istio.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: asm-igx-aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: aks-istio-ingress
  creationTimestamp: "0.0.0.0"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: azure-service-mesh-istio-ingress-gateway-addon-1.0.0-0.0.0.0
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: asm-ingress-aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: 0.0.0.0
    istio: aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
  name: aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
  namespace: aks-istio-ingress
  resourceVersion: "0.0.0.0"
  uid: 0.0.0.0
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 0.0.0.0
  clusterIPs:
  - 0.0.0.0
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: 0.0.0.0
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 0.0.0.0
    port: 0.0.0.0
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 0.0.0.0
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 0.0.0.0
    port: 0.0.0.0
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 0.0.0.0
  - name: https
    nodePort: 0.0.0.0
    port: 0.0.0.0
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 0.0.0.0
  selector:
    app: aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
    istio: aks-istio-ingressgateway-external
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 0.0.0.0
```

Tried to use kubectl commands, but no luck
Unable to find the corresponding helm charts that automatically deployed and managed aks istio ingress and other resources like LB

Comment: To preserve source IPs until they reach your destination containers, you need to set externalTrafficPolicy to Local in the service definition. However, you mentioned that using kubectl edit or patch did not work and Azure platform keeps reverting the changes you've made to their defaults. This could be because the AKS managed Istio uses Helm charts to deploy and manage resources like the ingress and load balancer. You can try updating the Helm chart values to set externalTrafficPolicy to Local. You can find the Helm chart values by running `helm get values RELEASE_NAME -n NAMESPACE`

Comment: Unfortunately, using Helm to update the values doesn't work since I've got no access to chart repo information. Installing AKS Istio is automated but non-customizable installation; I've got the chart name, release name, version and some other meta data, none of which suffices to update the chart :*(

Comment: Since Helm adjustments are not feasible without access to the chart repository, the alternative is to directly modify the service using kubectl to change its externalTrafficPolicy. use - `kubectl patch svc istio-ingress -n istio-ingress --patch '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'`  update istio-ingress with your namespace . These are the only two ways I can see.

Comment: Yes, there're only two ways to modify a resource in k8s and helm; seems like it's time to knock Azure community doors

Answer (score 1):

Given the details of your setup and the need to modify the `externalTrafficPolicy` of the Istio Ingress Gateway to `Local`, here's how to proceed based on the Helm deployment of your Istio components, specifically targeting the `istio-ingress` release in the `istio-ingress` namespace.

If the `istio-ingress` Helm release is using default values, you'll need to create a custom values file to override the `externalTrafficPolicy` for the Istio Ingress Gateway service.

1. *Create a new YAML file* named `custom-values.yaml`.
2. *Add the following content* to `custom-values.yaml`, assuming the `gateway` Helm chart structure allows for specifying service properties:
3. *Apply the Changes with Helm*
4. *Upgrade your Helm release* with the custom values to modify the `externalTrafficPolicy`. Run the following command in your terminal:

```
helm upgrade istio-ingress <chart-location> -n istio-ingress -f custom-values.yaml
```

Replace `<chart-location>` with the chart reference used during the initial installation.

5. *Verify the service's `externalTrafficPolicy`* is now set to `Local` by running:

```
 kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-ingress -o jsonpath="{.spec.externalTrafficPolicy}"
```

Example:
My istio setup
[image]

In my case, the `istio-ingress` Helm release is using default values, therefore I will create a custom values file to override the `externalTrafficPolicy` for the Istio Ingress Gateway service as below-

```
vim custom-values.yaml
```

```yaml
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

Now, how to know where exactly to modify?
For that, do a `helm show values istio/gateway`
[image]

here, based on the output of `helm show values istio/gateway`, to modify the `externalTrafficPolicy` for the Istio Ingress Gateway to `Local`, you should focus on the `service` section of the values. It's clear from the values output that `externalTrafficPolicy` is directly configurable under the `service` section. that's why I have modified my custom-values.yaml accordingly.

With your `custom-values.yaml` file now correctly structured, apply the changes

```
helm upgrade istio-ingress istio/gateway -n istio-ingress -f custom-values.yaml --wait
```

[image]

Now verify-

```
kubectl get svc istio-ingress -n istio-ingress -o jsonpath='{.spec.externalTrafficPolicy}'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and time; however, I've got no information regarding chart repo information; neither do I have it locally, which, presumably, prevents me from applying any changes. It's a bit strange that I can't make any changes on a chart that's deployed without the original chart itself referenced locally or remotely

Comment: you want to find the [chart](https://i.imgur.com/85plcYx.png) [name](https://i.imgur.com/B25cTWD.png) ?

Comment: Oh no, not yours :) Azure manages and deploys the given chart over the cloud, which doesn't let me modify it post-deployment. All I got chart name or release name but they're not enough to manipulate the chart if I don't provide the repository info to helm in such fashion as `helm upgrade asm-igx-aks-istio-ingressgateway-external ${repo}/azure-service-mesh-istio-ingress-gateway-addon --reuse-values --namespace aks-istio-ingress --set service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local`.